# Jquery Multiselect plugin filter conflicts with single select

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am using Jquery Multiselect plugin to filer my select dropdown. This plugin works fine except 1 thing is that when I type something in filter box then nothing is showing means that my **type word** is not showing. But when I remove the **bootstrap.min.css** from my file then it's working and my type word is showing. I think **Jquery UI** that multiselect filter plugin is using conflicts with bootstrap.min.css but I can't figure out. Please help me out. Below is my code and also check the **screenshot**.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.multiselect_1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.multiselect.filter.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.multiselect_1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.multiselect.filter.js"></script>

<select name="industry" id="industry" class="industry" style="width:305px;" onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('product_type'));" required>
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected>Choose Industry*</option>
    <option value="Agriculture & Food">Agriculture & Food</option>
    <option value="Apparel, Textiles & Accessories">Apparel, Textiles & Accessories</option>
    <option value="Auto & Tranportation">Auto & Tranportation</option>
    <option value="Bags, Shoes & Accessories">Bags, Shoes & Accessories</option>
  </select>

<select name="product_type" id="product_type" style="width:305px;">

    </select>
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery("#product_type").multiselect({
                minWidth: 360, multiple: false,
                selectedList: 1
            }).multiselectfilter({width:250});

function configureDropDownLists(ddl1,ddl2) {


    var AgricultureFood = ['Agricultural Growing Media', 'Agricultural Waste', 'Animal Products', 'Beans'];
    var ApparelTextilesAccessories = ['Apparel Design Services', 'Apparel Processing Services', 'Apparel Stock'];

    switch (ddl1.value) {
        case 'Agriculture & Food':
            ddl2.options.length = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < AgricultureFood.length; i++) {
                createOption(ddl2, AgricultureFood[i], AgricultureFood[i]);
            }
            break;
        case 'Apparel, Textiles & Accessories':
            ddl2.options.length = 0; 
        for (i = 0; i < ApparelTextilesAccessories.length; i++) {
            createOption(ddl2, ApparelTextilesAccessories[i], ApparelTextilesAccessories[i]);
            }
            break;

            default:
                ddl2.options.length = 0;
            break;
    }
     jQuery('#product_type').multiselect('refresh');

}

    function createOption(ddl, text, value) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = value;
        opt.text = text;
        ddl.options.add(opt);

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to high z-index for multi select list

Comment: @LaljiTadhani can you please update my code for better understanding. Thanks.

Comment: @LaljiTadhani I don't know how to use JS Fiddle. can you please guide me where should I add Z-index. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to add high `z-index` to `#product_type`

```
#product_type{z-index:99999999;}
```

Comment: It's not working.. When I remove Bootstrap.min.css then it's working. what is the problem..

Comment: How I include files in Js fiddle?

Comment: right side to "External Resources " add to live url

Comment: I want to add local files. how I include local files?

Comment: Lalji can I upload files on google drive and then you will have a look at this. I will be very thank full to you.

Comment: give me link in js fiddle